# data frame visibility - on/off like layers in arcgis 10

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcmap, arcgis-desktop, visualisation

I have two or more data frames in the table of contents area. Is there a way for changing data frame visibility in layout view of arcgis 10? I mean, similar to layers having option of on/off. I have seen in side the data frame, we can on/off layers but I want to do on/off for the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way that I know to do this in precisely the manner you describe.

If a data frame appears in Layout View then it always appears in the Table of Contents and vice versa.

However, you can toggle a data frame into Draft Mode on the Frame tab of its Properties and I suspect that this may address your use case.

Comment: I just checked this draft mode and it is giving similar result as "turn all layers off" . My need is to switch off the frame and its contents without disturbing the frame so that when I need it, I will simply switch on instead create a frame and adding layers into it.

Comment: It's a different function because the layers are still turned on - just not taking the time to redraw each time you move the data frame.